# Java - System.exit() and scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, system.exit

Assuming I have a scanner open, whether it is from `System.in` or from a file, and at some point in the program I'm activating `System.exit()`, (and didn't call to `scanner.close()` before), how (and if) it affects the scanner?

I was thinking since the `system.exit()` method shuts down the JVM, that everything associated with the scanner will be closed properly, but I didn't find any specific info about that case. For example - will the file that was opened by the scanner be unlocked ("freed" from the scanner) after `System.exit()`? Will all the relevant processes that are being activated at `scanner.close()` will be "activated" as well by the `System.exit()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanner is a stream, so when the program terminates the stream is automatically closed for you, however it is bad practice to not close streams, because in larger longer running programs they can cause problems, so yes everything closes properly but as said earlier it is bad practice.

If you have to many streams open at a time it will crash with an outOfMemoryError, here is an example of this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
LinkedList<Scanner> list = new LinkedList<>();
while(true)
    list.add(new Scanner(System.in));
}
```

so if you dont close your streams after a long time this memory error will result, also note that this error is not caused because there are too many items in the list it is because of the streams

EDIT:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner first = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner second = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = first.nextInt();
    int y = second.nextInt();
    System.out.println("First scan returns: " + x);
    System.out.println("Second scan returns: " + y);
    first.close();
    second.close();
}
```

As you can see you can open more than one System.in scanner, however when reading into a variable you have to specify what scanner object you would want to use.  However of course this is pointless and i cant think of any reason why you would need more than one System.in scanner open at a time.

Comment: So all the files that were opened by scanners will be closed at system.exit()?
Can you please give an example of an optional problem that can happen in larger programs?

Comment: @Mickey yes, all files and streams that were opened will be closed like they would have been had you called the close method, now a problem that could happen in large programs would be an OutOfMemoryError, becuase you can only have so many steams open at a time, so for most programs even large ones it would take a while to reach this limit, but if you have a server or a program that needs to run for a long time this could cause it to crash.

Comment: thanks.
For the example that you have edited in the comment, is it possible to open more than one `system.in` scanner? As far as I know you can't.
Also, how is the `OutOfMemoryError` connected to the `System.exit()` part? I didn't quite understand that.

Comment: @Mickey yes it is possible to open more than one System.in scanner, however you would have to specify which one you want to use when reading input i will edit in an example in the above answer

Comment: @Mickey also the OutOfMemoryError is not directly connected to System.exit(), however if the error occurs the program will crash which effectively does the same thing as System.exit(), and will close all the streams for you.

Comment: thanks!
So to summarize, system.exit() isn't recommended as a habit for exiting from programs, but shouldn't make a problem with closing scanners correctly at runtime.

Comment: System.exit() is an acceptable way to exit a program, however it really depends what the program is suppose to do, if you have a program that does some calculations you would not need to use System.exit(), because once it is finished the program will exit itself, however say you have a game, the game does not know how long the user will have the program open so it needs to call System.exit() when the user clicks the quit button to exit.  Once a program exits however, it doesn't matter if it crashed, exited normally, or called System.exit() all streams are closed for you automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I would answer your questions this way. The OS that the java process runs on is a well written and infinitely tested software. When a process exits (such as a java process) then the OS will:

- Make available the memory (RAM) used by the java process i.e. the memory is freed.
- The file descriptors that the java process held are cleaned out. This would include any files that it was reading or writing to etc.
- And so on.

But this does not mean that the best practices are not followed by the Java process. Let me give an example: imagine the java process has two threads running - one of them is updating a file and the other invokes exit. The file can become corrupted. Therefore, if this method is invoked, best practice dictates that shutdown hooks are programmed to take care of such situations. These hooks should attempt to close resources and do other kinds of housekeeping as well.

Also perhaps this will help: once System.exit() is invoked then the code proceeding to it will not be executed. So if you have a scanner.close() that will not be executed unless it is in a shutdown hook. Of course, the OS will free up the file descriptor on the process exit.

Comment: That's not really that great an example because a file can become 'corrupted' in that way in a completely single-threaded program that closes everything, has exit hooks, etc.

Comment: I just gave one example of what might happen when the best practices are not followed. Never said that that is the only way a file can be corrupted. :-)

Comment: It's not really illustrative of why these are 'best practices' since they don't actually prevent what you claim they prevent.

Comment: Well I disagree since shutdown hooks are best practice. I rest my case.

Comment: 'it's a best practice because it's a best practice, I rest my case' is powerful non-argument.